# How to store multiple checkbox values to database in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I need to store checkbox values into the database. I have tried so many examples, but still am not able to do that, Here I will give you my code and give me the solution for this.

**My Blade File**

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="hobbies" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Hobbies</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="Readbooks"/> Readbooks
        <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="Games"/> Games
        <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="Music"/> Music
        @if ($errors->has('hobbies'))
            <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('hobbies') }}</span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

**My Controller File**

```
public function postRegistration(Request $request)
{   
    $data = $request->all();
    $check = $this->create($data);

    return redirect("login")->withSuccess('Great! please login.');
}

public function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'hobbies' => $data->implode([',', (array) $data->get('hobbies')]),
     ]);
  }
```

**Error:Call to a member function implode() on array**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you use the implode method. And like the error says; you try to call a method on an array, because `$data` is an array and not an object.

And last, `$data->get('hobbies')` will also cause you problems, because the `get()` helper is not working on an array.

This is what you need:

```
return User::create([
    'hobbies' => implode(',', (array) $data['hobbies']),
]);
```

Comment: Yes sure, I have done it. Can you help me the edit and update? I have posted the question

Comment: @Karthika I just commented on your new question, take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

When you have inputs like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="Readbooks"/> Readbooks
<input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="Games"/> Games
<input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="Music"/> Music
```

The POST data received by the server includes `hobbies` as an array.  You can confirm this by inspecting the received request in your controller:

```
public function postRegistration(Request $request) {
    dd($request);
}
```

Since `$request->hobbies` is already an array, there is no need to cast it with `(array)`.

In the code you've shown, you are trying to `implode()` your hobbies.  `implode()` generates a string, so if the `hobbies` field you are trying to populate in the database is a string, you simply need to implode that received array of `hobbies`:

```
// Will generate a string like: "Readbooks,Music"
implode(',', $request->hobbies);
```

Putting it into your code:

```
public function create($data) {
    return User::create(['hobbies' => implode(',', $data->hobbies)];
}
```